# Error while indexing documents in solr - SolrException

Tags: solr

I am using the following code to index documents in solr server.

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/solr";            
SolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(urlString);
java.io.File file=new java.io.File("C:\\Users\\Guruprasad\\Desktop\\Search\\47975832.doc");

if (file.canRead()) {

        System.out.println("adding " + file);
        try {
            ContentStreamUpdateRequest req = new ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
            String parts[] = file.getName().split("\\.");
            String type = "text";
            if (parts.length>1) {
                type = parts[1];
            }
            req.addFile(file);
            req.setParam("literal.id", file.getAbsolutePath());
            req.setParam("literal.name", file.getName());
            req.setParam("literal.content_type", type);
            req.setParam("uprefix", "attr_");
            req.setParam("fmap.content", "attr_content");
            req.setAction(ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);

            solr.request(req);* //**Line no 36** here i am getting exception
```

While executing this code i am getting following exception.

**Exception:** org.apache.solr.common.SolrException

**Exception message:**

```
Internal Server Error Internal Server Error request: 

 http://localhost:8080/solr/update/extract?literal.id=C:\Users\Guruprasad\Desktop\Search\47975832.doc&literal.name=47975832.doc&literal.content_type=doc&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=attr_content&commit=true&waitFlush=true&waitSearcher=true&wt=javabin&version=2
```

**Exception trace:**

```
at   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:435)
at   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
at   com.solr.search.test.IndexFiles.indexDocs(IndexFiles.java:36)*
```

Any help will be useful

Answer (score 0):

i dont't suggest you use dih to index your database data, you can use solrj to index your data , solrj is simple , if you can use jdbc , then things is simple , you can use solrj build solr document and batch data commit to solr server . there are a solrj wiki , hope it can help you [solrj wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)

Answer (score 0):

solr 5.0 comes with inbuilt utility DIH handler for indexing data from database which you are using but its configuration is important and tricky could you please post your configuration of DIH handler or share logs of import , it looks like configuration problem to me